# RoR - Access images from assets to Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, select2-rails

Following function correctly show images accessed from /assets/images/icons/... directory, when tested locally;

```
function formatShapes(item) {
  if (!item.id) return item.text;
  return "<img height='20px' src='/assets/icons/shape_" + item.id.toLowerCase() + ".png'/> " + item.text;
}
$("select#q_shape_eq").select2({
  formatResult: formatShapes,
  formatSelection: formatShapes,
  escapeMarkup: function(m) { return m; }
});
```

Images in /icons/ directory are:

1. shape_low.png
2. shape_medium.png
3. shape_high.png

These are correctly bind in **select2** dropdown against `item.id`. But as soon as I deploy the code to production (Heroku) it does not show images in select2-rails dropdown. The reason is that the image path in production seems to be something like '/assets/logo-200a00a193ed5e297bb09ddd96afb953.png'. How can I refer to that dynamic path on production server ?

Thanks